# split string based on comma delimiter

Tags: java

what is wrong in the following code?

```
String selectedCountriesStr = countries.replaceAll("[", "").replaceAll("]", "").trim();
String[] selectedCountriesArr = selectedCountriesStr.split(",");
```

Input String `[10000,20000,304050,766666]`

Getting error `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 0`

Comment: use `replace()` instead of `replaceAll()`

Comment: @MarcoForberg: That's an *answer* (and a good one), not a comment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That isn't the reason for the error message though.  It would probably get downvoted into oblivion if it had been placed as an answer.

Comment: @BLaZuRE this is the reason why i try to avoid "snap shot answers" ;)

Comment: @MarcoForberg: Well, you could say why the error occurred, and then suggest the `replace` solution (which is undoubtedly better of the goal is to replace `[` characters -- regular expressions aren't free).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The problem is that i'm not to familiar with regular expressions but it was obvious that changing the method would suffice in this case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to escape square brackets because `replaceAll()` interprets the first argument as a regular expression:

```
replaceAll("\\[", "")
            ^^
```

because, as the error message tells you, the are used for character classes in a regex. Double backslashes are necessary, because `"\["` would be an invalid escape sequence. Since the backslash is escaped, the regex engine only receives one backslash.

Also, you can use

```
replace("[", "")
```

it will also replace **all** occurrences of the given CharSequence as is.

You can read more about it in [**JavaDoc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 6):

Brackets are regex metacharacters, you need to prefix them with a backslash:

```
.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "")
```

Also, since this is a simple string substitution, you'd better use `.replace()`:

```
.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     String str = "hi,hello,abc,example,problems";
    String[] splits = str.split(",");

    System.out.println("splits.size: " + splits.length);

    for(String asset: splits){
    System.out.println(asset);

    }
```

Split function will easily split your string like this